# Is copying Summae really this easy?

Tags: ars-magica-5

ArM5 page 166 says that when you've accumulated as many points as the *level* of the summa you've copied it; and points are accumulated at 6+Prof(Scribe) per season, or three times that if doing it quickly.

- At that rate a skilled scribe could copy one of the roots of the arts in half a season and then be sitting around twiddling their thumbs for the rest of it.
- Writing a summa on an ability is 5x as hard, but copying it isn't?
- There's practically no summa that can't be quickly copied in a season by anyone!

These things all seem implausible; but I can't find any errata for it.

Comment: Can you articulate why you find this implausible? A skilled scribe copies for several weeks straight: surely he'll get a lot done?

Answer (score 5):

That rule is correct to RAW, and has worked without issue in play for my groups in the past. Your third dot point is wrong because of the skills involved.

Note the additional notes about how a book may become corrupted due to the scribe not having the appropriate skills needed to comprehend the language the text is written in, or the subject matter of the text (also on ArM5 p.166).

For example - a typical scribe will have a high scribe score, but will not have a score in Magic Theory, which then risks corruption of every Art, Spell, or Parma book they copy. Likewise the supernatural books.

This leads to magi finding very useful tasks for their apprentices.

Btw - there is a much more complex set of rules for scribing books, different book types, and different embellishment in the Covenants 5e book. It explains exactly what corruption is, how it affects the character, and what can be done about it.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning the Cow and Calf oath here

Comment: I was trying to stick to the RAW mechanics of what is plausible rather than the in-game setting material. As I've not had a huge issue with the rules in this area I thought it was worth noting why the approach isn't 100% correct, and not muddy with setting fluff. True enough though, C&C Oath would be useful as a foot note to discussion of magical books, as would the different ways the tribunal source books handle trade of books. Again, Covenants source book is the place to look.